# validation on name field of javascript form (html webpage)

Tags: javascript

I have been searching for a while now and cant find this.

what I want is to have validation on the "name" field of a form, that if the user enters "a" all the names beginning with "a" will be displayed and so forth when they carry on entering more letter, it will get more defined.

I just want this validation for the "name" field and I already have the 200 "names" that are the most popular, that a user can enter.

any guides on how to easily achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting you right you're looking for Ajax auto-complete.

I recommend Jquery AutoComplete: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Sample of use:
**(don't forget to include the Jquery UI js file)**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableNames = [
            "Adam",
            "Andrey",
            "Aharon",
            "Antonio",
            "Kavin"
        ];
        $( "#names" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableNames
        });
    });
    </script>


<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="names">Write your name:: </label>
    <input id="names">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, yes, this is close to what im looking for. but im having trouble understanding that code. where is the source code that I can easily edit and where should I put my 200 names?